# How to fix formatting so the string does not repeat in the for loop?

Tags: python

My problem is that when I run my code, my format repeats the same name twice for each output, just like shown below:

```
MW SCHEDULE OF ['RAM PAR 3500', 'RAM PAR 4500']  is 136.0 MW 
MW SCHEDULE OF ['RAM PAR 3500', 'RAM PAR 4500']  is 136.0 MW
```

```py
FROM_BUS=[126,126]
TO_BUS=[126,126]
CKT=[1,2]
NAME=['RAM 1', 'RAM 2']
for FROM_BUS,TO_BUS,CKT in zip(FROM_BUS, TO_BUS, CKT):
    [ierr, cmpval] = psspy.brnflo(FROM_BUS,TO_BUS,str(CKT))
    cmpvali=abs(cmpval.real)
    output10='MW SCHEDULE OF {}  is {} MW '.format(NAME,(round(cmpvali,0)))
    print(output10)
```

Rather, I would like my results to be like this:

```
MW SCHEDULE OF ['RAM PAR 3500']  is 136.0 MW
MW SCHEDULE OF ['RAM PAR 4500']  is 136.0 MW
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does `NAME` relate to `cmpvali`? You're not iterating over the values in `NAME`, so of course it prints both.

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but maybe the following is something like what you want?

```
FROM_BUS=[126,126]
TO_BUS=[126,126]
CKT=[1,2]
NAME=['RAM 1', 'RAM 2']
# ADD NAME TO zip()
for FROM_BUS,TO_BUS,CKT,NAME in zip(FROM_BUS, TO_BUS, CKT, NAME):
    [ierr, cmpval] = psspy.brnflo(FROM_BUS,TO_BUS,str(CKT))
    cmpvali=abs(cmpval.real)
    output10='MW SCHEDULE OF {}  is {} MW '.format(NAME,(round(cmpvali,0)))
    print(output10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `NAME` from the `zip` function, try this:
(also cleaned up your code a bit and fixed your variable naming)

```
FROM_BUS = [126, 126]
TO_BUS = [126, 126]
CKT = [1, 2]
NAME = ['RAM 1', 'RAM 2']
for from_bus, to_bus, ckt, name in zip(FROM_BUS, TO_BUS, CKT, NAME):
    [ierr, cmpval] = psspy.brnflo(from_bus, to_bus, str(ckt))
    cmpvali = abs(cmpval.real)
    output10 = 'MW SCHEDULE OF {}  is {} MW '.format(name, (round(cmpvali, 0)))
    print(output10)
```